# What's the difference between Radio r = Radio("PSR", 100.8) and Radio("PSR", 100.8)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, constructor, initialization, variable-initialization

I'm new to C++ and trying to understand something. I have this code in my main.cpp:

```
Radio r = Radio("PSR", 100.8);
```

or that code:

```
Radio r("PSR", 100.8);
```

Both seem to work and doing the same thing. So what's the difference?

Comment: details matter. `type name();` is a function declaration. In your actual code it isnt `name();` but `name(parameter)`

Comment: `type name()` is declaration and definition of the variable `name` of type `type` and call to the `type` constructor all at once, `type name = type()` is also declaration and definition of var `name`, but it is initialized by copy assignment of an anonymous instance of `type`, created with the `type()` constructor. Crystal clear, right? Well that's C++ for you...

Comment: In the snippets provided, they both work and both do the same thing.  Obligatory [The Nightmare of Initialization in C++](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DTlWPgX6zs) by Nicolai Josuttis.  An hour long presentation on the initialization syntax pain point in C++.

Comment: @joH1 no. `type name()` does not declare a variable called `name` of type `type`. It declares a function: https://godbolt.org/z/Pe65q9r5o

Comment: In C++ there is about dozen ways to initialise something and sometimes the differences matter but sometimes not. It is made to keep it complicated as job security.

Comment: @ÖöTiib job security of book writers, right? ;) I didnt meet any mortal programmer who unstood all C++ initialization

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number indeed, sorry, I oversimplified the expressions for clarity, but too much (my C++ is a bit rusty)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Radio r = Radio("PSR", 100.8);` is [copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) while `Radio r("PSR", 100.8);` is [direct initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization).

##### C++17

From C++17 due to [mandatory copy elison](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision#Mandatory_elision_of_copy/move_operations) both are the equivalent.

```
Radio r = Radio("PSR", 100.8); //from C++17 this is same as writing Radio r("PSR", 100.8);
```

##### Prior C++17

But **prior to C++17**, the first case `Radio r = Radio("PSR", 100.8);` may result in the creation of a temporary using which `r` is copy initialized. This is because prior to C++17, there was [non-mandatory copy elison](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision#Mandatory_elision_of_copy/move_operations).

---

Another thing to note is that if you were to write:

```
type name(); //this is a function declaration
```

the above is a declaration for a function named `name` which has the return type of `type` and has `0` parameters.