# Compiler optimisation C++: is X a() not same as X a = X()?

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization

I was trying something around default constructor and stumbled upon this kind of situation

```
static int e = 0;
class X
{
public:
    X()
    {
        e = 10;
    }
    ~X()
    {
        e = 11;
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    if(e ==   88) return 88;
    X a();
    printf("%d", e);
    return 0;
}
```

The output of above code when compiled on visual studio 2010 with default optimisation parameter is 0. Constructor and destructor of X completely gets ignored.

When I change code to

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    if(e ==   88) return 88;
    X a = X();
    printf("%d", e);
    return 0;
}
```

I get expected output that is 10

I wan't to understand why 1st code doesn't works and 2nd does work?

Comment: This is unrelated to optimizations. `X a();` declares `a` as a function taking no arguments and returning an `X` object by value. It's as simple as that. Use plain `X a;` for a default-constructed `X` object named `a`.

Comment: @Shubham See [What's the difference between type name() and type name = type()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72434416/whats-the-difference-between-type-name-and-type-name-type)

Comment: The possibility to use braces for initialization, `X a{};` was added partially because of this. With braces it can never be a function.

Comment: In the early design of C++, the decision was made that `X a(void);` no-parameter function declaration could be expressed as `X a();`  (There is some cross-over with **C** history, too, which has it's only interesting journey & evolution.)  One result of that is `X a();` is interpreted as a function declaration, instead of a local variable with default initialization.  C++11 added `X a{};` for default construction (in particular, for member variable declarations), but the common practice is `X a;` for local variables.